# Control one Jquery Mobile slider by

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I want to let the user pick a number of USD and show the EUR equivalent (or the other way around), I'm using a JQuery Mobile/PHP page and was thinking of using two sliders, one for EUR and one for USD and whenever a user changes the value of one slider the other one changes accordingly. Anyone that knows how to do this?

```
<div id="content">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="slider1">
                    USD
                </label>
                <input id="slider1" type="range" name="slider" value="50" min="0" max="100"
                data-highlight="false">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="slider2">
                    EUR
                </label>
                <input id="slider2" type="range" name="slider" value="50" min="0" max="100"
                data-highlight="false">
            </div>
        </form>
</div> <!-- end #content -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few months ago I made something similar.

Take a look at this working example and use it to for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PzTeX/

```
$(document).on("slidestop", "input#us, input#uk, input#japan",function() {
    $(this).mouseup();
    var changeVal = ($(this).val() - $(this).attr('min'))/($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min'));
    changeSliders(changeVal, $(this).attr('id'));    
});

function changeSliders(changeVal, sliderID){
    $("input#us, input#uk, input#japan").each(function(){
        var newValue = parseFloat($(this).attr('min')) + parseFloat(($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min')))*changeVal;
        if($(this).attr('id') != sliderID) {    
            $(this).val(newValue);
        }
    });
    $("input#europe, input#us, input#uk, input#japan").slider('refresh');    
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is great. One question, is it possible to add some code to make the two other sliders follow also if a value is typed in the box to the left (instead of the slider being dragged)?